# How to convert a String to a 2D char array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

I am trying to convert a string into a 2D char array.

So for example, if the input string is: `+dd+babd+b_a+ddc`

The output should be a 2D char array which looks like the following:

```
+dd+

babd

+b_a

+ddc
```

The code below is what I have tried so far. Here I'm trying to get the character at index i and store it in a 2D char array at location [0][0] then the next character at location [0][1] and so on.

[Please note, I added the @param comments in the looping body to help you understand what each of the parameters is storing. I understand the @param should be on top of the method head and not in the body].

```
public Board(String startConfig, String endConfig) {

        int row = 4;
        int column = 4;
        // @param startConfig currently stores the string +dd+babd+b_a+ddc.
        // @param endConfig is currently unused.
        char[][] boardArray = new char[row][column]; // Creates a 4x4 board.
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                boardArray[i][j] = startConfig.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(boardArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am truly stuck and can't think of anything else. I've already tried using .toCharArray but this method converts a string to a 1D char array, which is of little use to me.

I want to thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another counter for the `String` offset

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < column; j++) {
        boardArray[i][j] = startConfig.charAt(offset++);
        System.out.println(boardArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

or as per Tim's excellent answer, the offset can be calculated as `j + i*column`

For the output to match try

```
int offset = 0;
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < column; j++) {
        boardArray[i][j] = startConfig.charAt(offset++);
        System.out.print(boardArray[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println ();
    // uncomment below line if you want a blank line
    // System.out.println ();
}
```

Comment: see me edit, should fix your output

Comment: This one should match.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but you need to assign each position using both the current row and column.  In this case, the following expression determines the index of the current character:

```
j + i*column   <--- offset by this many rows
^^^
current column

for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < column; j++) {
        boardArray[i][j] = startConfig.charAt(j + i*column);
        System.out.println(boardArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  How are you using the 2D array to generate the output?

Comment: @Ree No ingenuity, but I have upvoted your question in any case.